# URL tuckey - outbound rule

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm having trouble with tuckey URL outbound rules. I was able to set up inbound rules, but I need to convert a URL using outbound rule. We are using tuckey with Spring.

Outbound rule:

```
<outbound-rule>
    <from>^/domain.mvc?domainId=([0-9]+)&amp;domainName=([a-z]+)$</from>
    <to type="forward">/signin.mvc/$1/$2</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

JSTL:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/domain.mvc?domainId=0123&amp;domainName=abc" />">
```

Although it says processing outbound rule it's not forwarding to my URL. In the url-rewritestatus it shows all my rules but doesn't show matched ones. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If it's not Apache httpd server (more than 60% of the world), but a iis server (which less than 40% of the world uses) please add this in your question tags.

Comment: we are using tomcat with spring and jstl. and following Paul tuckey's URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark ? has a special meaning in a regex. You will need to escape it with a backslash.

```
^/domain.mvc\?domainId=([0-9]+)&amp;domainName=([a-z]+)$
```

Comment: It 's appending my root before domain.mvc but not applying the rule.